# Heuristic Function in a maze in C

Tags: c

```
int heuristic(Maze* maze, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{    
    return abs(x0 - x1) + abs(y0 - y1);    
}
```

I am searching heuristic function for a maze which includes the altitudes. I found a code with two parameters(x and y). Is there a possibility to have heuristic function which includes axe z(for altitudes) ?

Comment: Of course it is possible. Now that you see a heuristic function with two coordinates, it should be easy to see how it can be restricted to one coordinate, or extended to three. Did you try it?

Comment: is it 
return abs(x0 - x1) + abs(y0 - y1) + abs(z0-z1); 
?

Comment: It is indeed, provided you also add two more parameters to the signature (not just return).

Comment: int heuristic(Maze* maze, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int z0, int z1)
{    
    return abs(x0 - x1) + abs(y0 - y1)+ abs(z0-z1);    
}  ?

Comment: Exactly. Just as long as you understand it is just one possible heuristic (usually called [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)); there are many possible heuristics for any given purpose, and mazes are no exception. For example, you could use Euclidean distance instead.

Comment: Whichever gives you better results for your specific application. Test, then pick. Or just use whichever you think is best; it's called "heuristic" for a reason :p

Answer (score 0):

```
int heuristic(Maze* maze, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int z0, int z1)
{
    return abs(x0 - x1) + abs(y0 - y1)+ abs(z0-z1);
}
```

? – alberto